# removing 'greyed outness' of jquery datepicker's disabled dates

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I've implemented an instance of jquery datepicker on my website. 
I wish to display dates on my calendar, which works perfectly, but I want to disable any form of interaction with it. 
One thing I tried was to disable all the dates, which works great - as in the user can't click on any, but they all get greyed out and I don't want that to happen. 
I've tried adding various CSS to my code, but it doesn't remove the greying out / dimming effect of the disabled dates.

Does anyone know how to do this - or perhaps have a better way of simply disabling the user interaction without actually specifying that the dates are 'disabled'

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Date-Scatter - Latest Statement Assessments</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>
    .ui-highlight .ui-state-default{
        background: red !important;
        border-color: red !important;
        color: white !important;
    }

    div.ui-datepicker{
        font-size:10px;
    }

    #datepicker-container{  
        text-align:center;
    }

    #datepicker-center{
        display:inline-block;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">       
    var dates = ['2016-01-05','2016-01-15','2016-01-25'];
    jQuery(function(){
         $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            numberOfMonths: [2, 3], 
            changeMonth: false,
            changeYear: false,
            defaultDate: '-5m',
            beforeShowDay : function(date){
                var y = date.getFullYear().toString(); // get full year
                var m = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString(); // get month.
                var d = date.getDate().toString(); // get Day
                if(m.length == 1){ m = '0' + m; } // append zero(0) if single digit
                if(d.length == 1){ d = '0' + d; } // append zero(0) if single digit
                var currDate = y+'-'+m+'-'+d;
                if(dates.indexOf(currDate) >= 0){
                    return [false, "ui-highlight"]; 
                }else{
                    return [false];
                }                   
            }
        });
        $('#datepicker').find('.ui-datepicker-next').remove();  
        $('#datepicker').find('.ui-datepicker-prev').remove();
    })
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="datepicker-container" style="text-align:center; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold">
    Date-Scatter - Latest Statement Assessments<br/><br/>
        <div id="datepicker-center">
            <div id="datepicker">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should be able to do this with css targeting `.ui-datepicker-unselectable.ui-state-disabled`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion... 
I also had a sudden thought that might help others out too... 
My datepicker is in a div, so I've simply removed all mouse interaction with the div!!!

CSS

```
.disabledbutton {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

and then `$("#datepicker").datepicker().addClass("disabledbutton")`

works for me!